# Could my partition setup on my Hitachi Travelstar be causing SMART spinup problems?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

I just purchased a refurb Samsung laptop for my girlfriend with a 500gb Hitachi Travelstar. I partitioned it and installed Win 7 (for required work related programs for her) / and 12.04 LTS (for general use, because she has basically become a Linux convert using my laptop... :) )

We've been using it for a couple weeks with no issues, but today disk utility reported a SMART error for spinup time...

Other details:
-originally put 12.04 LTS on first, then Win 7... That order of operations seemed to mess with GRUB, so i downloaded and ran boot-repair. This seemed to correct boot issues.

-when I decided to try to reboot to Win this morning after the error, I found that Win was suspended, and not shut down, so I shut it down completely and rebooted to 12.04... When I did this, the SMART spinup value changed:

with Win hibernating: Norm.: 31 ; Thresh.: 33, Value: 11 (msec)
with Win shut down: Norm.: 31 ; Thresh.: 33, Value: 1 (msec)

-I chose to encrypt her home folder (which I have NEVER done before, don't ask me why i did this time, i don't know...), and then found out that Hitachi Travelstars have built-in encryption? Is this correct? Is this an issue? I get an error at Ubuntu screen saying something about a '/dev/(?)/cryptswap/' not mounting/mounted, S for skip, M for manual rec... but neither keystroke yields a response.

***I will state now that I am not a novice, but definitely not an expert...*** :)

That being said, I guess I'm looking for some thoughts/help about the general situation such as:

-is there a possibility that choosing encryption did something?
-is it possible for SMART to be reporting this error falsely?
-how "imminent" is this failure, if SMART IS reporting correctly?
-would a backup/format/re-install possibly correct things?

Sorry for jamming so many ?'s in... I know it's frowned upon, but if this thing is going to blow up, I need to get it all out there ASAP.

Thank you in advance for any help...
-ASM

Answer (score 0):

No; if the SMART health says it is failing with too long of a spinup time, then it is time to replace the drive.